# How to pass a name value pair as a List to a method in java

Tags: java

I have to pass a name value pair of `myDate="2019-11-21"` as the third parameter to the below mentioned method call:

```
jsonParser.makeServiceCall(get_client_name_by_date_url, JsonServiceHandler.GET,List);
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `List` pass `Map<String, Date>` or `Map<String, String>`

Comment: I just have to pass "myDate" as the key and it's value as "2019-11-21". Kindly let me know an easier workaround... thanks...

Comment: Map<String, String> dates = new HashMap<>();
dates.put("myDate", "2019-11-21");
jsonParser.makeServiceCall(get_client_name_by_date_url, JsonServiceHandler.GET,dates);